# Exclude product with tag from all collection page liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm still very new to Shopify so my knowledge of it is very limited.

I've created a page where I want to show certain products with the tag "export". These products should never come up on the collection page (siteurl/collection/all).

I've tried excluding the products with the tag from the collection template but that only leaves gaps on the pages its excluding.

[image]

This is my current code:

```
{% for product in collection.products %}
    {% if product.tags contains 'export' %}{% continue %}{% endif %}
       My code for displaying the product
{% endfor %}
```

I've also tried:

```
{% for product in collection.products %}
    {% unless product.tags contains 'export' %}
       My code for displaying the product
    {% endunless %}
{% endfor %}
```

My thinking is that I'll need to set the conditions before I call my products so my pagination doesn't break. Is there a way to do this in Shopify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to know is that Liquid performs the initial action (`for product in collection.products`) before then performing the next one.

So the forloop grabs all of the products, and then your `if` statement removes those products. Unfortunately, the pagination has already performed the product split during the forloop, so when you remove the product, it removes it from the paginated result.

There is, annoyingly, no way around this.
The only realistic solution is to create your own `all` collection and then use smart filters to add everything except products tagged with `xyz`.

Comment: Thanks @ConduciveMammal, I was afraid this might be the case. Was really hoping there was some way to set conditions before the forloop.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work for you, it is rudimentary and includes some code that could be excluded but will help you understand how it works

CODE FOR YOUR COLLECTION TEMPLATE:

```
{% for product in collection.products %}
    <!-- Set the default value of "product_show" to "true" -->
    {% assign product_show = true %}

    <!-- We iterate all the tags inside the product checking if one of them EXACTLY matches with "Export" -->
    {% for tag in product.tags %}

        {% if tag == "export" %}
            <!-- If we find an "export" tag then we set product_show to "false" -->
            {% assign product_show = false %}

            <!-- When we find the label we exit the "FOR" loop -->
            {% break %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

    <!-- If the product has "product_show" then it will not be shown and will continue with the next product -->
    {% if product_show == "true" %}
        CODIGO DEL PRODUCTO
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I've tried it and I'm afraid like ConduciveMammal explained below Shopify already calculates the products to show per page when calling the  `for product in collection.products`  and therefore anything we add after it only creates empty spaces on the product page

Comment: The only way to generate an empty space using this is for the iteration to happen on the child object, otherwise it couldn't return an empty space since there would be no HTML tag to allocate that space.